# What requirements does ISO 20022 pose on a Stellar implementation?

Tags: stellar-core

To be ISO 20022 certified, what are the requirements, and how would the ISO 20022 data testing procedures would be performed on the Stellar platforms or other systems before going into Production?

If I wanted to extract the needed data to my own operations, are the API available to access the ledgers and copied blockchain transactions which were originated from our side?

Comment: Hi Ronald, welcome to Stack Exchange! I've removed most of the backstory and your signature, as that isn't central to the question. It's still [on the broad side though](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) but perhaps somebody is able to give you some pointers.